# java RMI grant class download from remote machine

Tags: java, classloader, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to run an application in which the server can execute Tasks loaded from clients.

```
interface TaskExecuter extends Remote
    <T> T executeTask(Task<T> t);

interface Task<T> 
    T execute();
```

this interfaces are known from both client and server. On server side I also have the class

```
class TaskExecuterImpl implements TaskExecuter
```

which is located in Tomcat's webapps directory, and server codebase references this location.

On client side I have the class

```
class SimpleTask implements Task<Integer>, Serializable
```

which is located in /home/pc/public/

client codebase is : -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///home/pc/public/-
client.policy is:

```
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission
        "*:0-65535","read,accept,connect,resolve";
    permission java.io.FilePermission 
        "/home/pc/public/","read";
    permission java.security.AllPermission;     
};
```

Client and server are located on different machines. Everything works correctly if I copy SimpleTask on the server, but I have a classNotFound exception due to a denied permission when ClassLoader tries to download SimpleTask if, as it should, SimpleTask is located only on Client's machine.

---

Comment: Post the stack trace, and clarify which host gets the exception. Is `file:///home/pc/public/-` accessible to the server?

Comment: client-side shows the exception, but it comes from the server. How can I verify that path is accessible to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your `file:///...` codebase URL almost certainly only has a meaning to the client. It's the server (in this situation) that has to use the codebase, so the codebase has to be set to something the server will understand. `file:` URLs don't qualify, unless they refer to shared drives, and unless they refer to the server's view of the shared drive. Use `FTP:` or `http:`.

Comment: even if I have no ftp or http server installed on the client?